# Any trick to manually check for app updates?

Tags: apps, store, nokia-lumia-920, app-update

Since the firmware update  know as 1308 I have an issue that the update checker is not working so I have to manually check app by app. Do you know any trick to force the checker?

Comment: Did you restart the phone and the problem persist?

Comment: Of course, I already reported the issue to Microsoft because it seems is a real problem that many users are dealing with.

Comment: Just an Off Topic, did you have cellular data, battery or overheat problems with previous firmware? I'm still waiting for 1308.

Comment: The regular, most of them got solved on 1308.

Comment: Just updated to 1308. Let me see how long does it take to show an update. Or not.

Comment: I'm still waiting for 1314!

Comment: Just confirmed I have the same issue in 1308.

Comment: Man, this thing is making me crazy. Just pop 3 updates. You sure no updates are shown in your phone after the update?

Comment: Last night I got 42 updates :P seems like it's working again.

Comment: Nokia said to me on twitter that I need to unassign other phone I have with the same Microsoft Account. But I didn't "buy" that.

Comment: Another updates were shown in my phone. You still think you have this problem? If not I will purge all comments.

Comment: The updates are behaving like a roller-coaster here, I think is better if you leave all the comments like a log of what's happening.

Comment: Other phone with a totally different setup behaving the same way... even with Amber installed.

Comment: After Black update, nothing has changed. However some rumors talk about [Windows Phone 8.1 (Blue) including a manual update checker](http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-81-features).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1, you can check for app updates manually from the Store app. To do so:

1. Open the Store app.
2. Expand the app bar by tapping on the three dots icon.
3. Go to Settings.
4. Scroll down, and under "App updates", tap the "Check for updates" button.

The number of updated apps will be shown in the Store app, as well as on its live tile if you have it pinned to your Start screen.

Comment: Cool, they have finally listened to us in the forums and added this feature. I will mark your answer as the correct because is what currently solves better the problem. However by the time of the question this simple solution didn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

You can use update pusher applications like *Lumia Pusher* and can add your list of applications that are to be checked for updates

Comment: Thanks but I'm already using SysApp Pusher app for this: http://twitpic.com/drnjw5

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any tricks to check all apps at once. Your only choice is verify one by one like you mention.

I'm got in touch with Nokia and they said no one complain about this.